# what does "glancing about him for support" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature

> Poppy brought a book. When everyone had been introduced she took the
> end chair and began to read with her hands round her face like blinkers.
>
> ‘This is the last time I let you do this,’ said Philip.
>
> ‘Do what?’
>
> ‘Read in company.’
>
> ‘But it’s boring!’
>
> ‘It’s rude.’
>
> Poppy smiled and shrugged. Athena stood by the door and watched.
> **Philip, glancing about him for support**, caught her eye.

Does the sentence in bold mean:

1. philip was glancing about him to find somewhere to lean his back or to make more room for himself?
2. philip was looking at others to be approved by them?

Source: The children's Bach by Helen Garner.

Comment: Philip wanted to see if others agreed with him, supporting his opinion that Poppy was a jerk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the second option, Philip is looking for approval from others. He chides Poppy for reading while company is present, and she shrugs it off as though she doesn't really care. He wants another adult to back him up, and he hopes that Athena might say something.

The phrase could take the first meaning you proposed depending on context, but it's not the case here. Poppy isn't saying anything shocking that would make Philip feel unsteady and need to sit down, and Philip would not look to Athena for physical support - he's instead looking to her for emotional/parental support.